# Vuetify get selected index from <v-select>

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, html-select

After several searches and several attempts, I finally found a way to get the selected index from a `<v-select>` element in Vuetify.

But I recognize that it's not clean code, but it worked and solved my problem.

However, I would be grateful if someone could help me to simplify this thing a bit.

Here is my code:

```html
<template>
    <v-select
        v-model="personSelected"
        @change="getIdFromPeopleSelect"
        :items="personData"
        label="Select a person"
        outlined>
    </v-select>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      personSelected: "",

      //objects inside this array was extracted from a firebase query ;-) //
      personData: [
        {name: "John", city: "New York"},
        {name: "Mary", city: "Berlin"},
        {name: "Claudia", city: "Dubai"}
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getIdFromPeopleSelect() {

      // this could be better to get selectedIndex from v-select
      return console.log(this.personData.findIndex(x => x.name=== this.personSelected));
    }
</script>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the reason for getting the index is to then get the object correlating to the selection, the better way is to use the [`return-object`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#return-object) prop.

Also use [`item-text`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#item-text) to specify the `name` field.

You can remove the `change` listener as `personSelected` will contain the object.

```html
<v-select
  v-model="personSelected"
  :items="personData"
  item-text="name"
  label="Select a person"
  return-object
  outlined>
</v-select>
```